# Socket.Receive() works as expected only when debug the code step by step

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, synchronous

I'm newbie in socket programming. I have a small application written in C# which uses the COM port to connect to a "key mapper" device which responds only if a matching command sent by the application. Ex: If I need to get some pin numbers from the mapper, I sent a hex command. Then I receive the correct response back. Now I'm trying to do the same activity using a socket connection with the unique IP address of the device as follows.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] sendCommand = new byte[] { 0x02, 0x24, 0x31, 0x95, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x03 };
    byte[] ReceivedVal = new byte[1024];
    IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.178.170"), 10001);
    Socket senderNew = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                  SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    waitLoop(5);
    try
    {
        senderNew.Connect(ipEndPoint);
    }
    catch(SocketException socProblem)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(socProblem.Message.ToString());
    }
    waitLoop(5);
    int test = senderNew.Receive(ReceivedVal);
    Console.Write("Starting bytes read : ");
    Console.WriteLine(test.ToString());
    waitLoop(5);

    int bytesSent = senderNew.Send(sendCommand);
    waitLoop(5);
    Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}", senderNew.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
    int bytesRec = senderNew.Receive(ReceivedVal);
    Console.Write("data bytes read : ");
    Console.WriteLine(bytesRec.ToString());
    waitLoop(5);

    QueryAllCodeResponseHandler(ReceivedVal);
    waitLoop(5);
    Console.Write("Number of Pin Codes read: ");
    Console.WriteLine(PinCodes.Length.ToString());
    senderNew.Close();
    GC.Collect();
    PinCodes = null;
    ReceivedVal = null;
    ipEndPoint = null;
    GC.Collect();
}
```

Expected result as follows:

[image]

When I debug it line by line, it works completely fine. But If I run it directly without any debug points or skip debugging line by line I get only 2 pins or 0 pins. Then I tried to use a 3rd party application write after this unsuccessful attempt and realized that it receives the rest of the pins from the previous attempt. Can someone help me spot where the issue is?

Comment: Why are you doing this : `byte[] ReceivedVal = new byte[1024];`? Just use a protocol you posted ( as an image ).. `byte[] ReceivedVal = new byte[12];` as you can see in the reference source `Socket.Receive` method calls native [`WinAPI` `recv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx) function which waits till the buffer ( `1024 bytes` in your case ) is filled.

Comment: Because I receive the result in decimal. And according to the protocol I don't receive only the pins but some other separators which I have to remove in the decoding process. And this is not the only command I can feed the device with.

Comment: You show code that has a bunch of `Console.WriteLine`s in it. Then you show expected output that you say is correct but it doesn't include any of the strings your code is writing to the console. It isn't at all clear where in the code the output you *are* showing was generated. There's no way for anyone else to tell what's happening in code you haven't shown. Read [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out, your code leaves some questions but (assuming your debugging steps are accurate) it seems that you are simply relying on the TCP protocol to decide when you are done receiving your response.

The device you are connecting to should use an **application defined protocol** to allow querying it. For example, the initial response will contain a byte count of the whole response to expect, or it will use a specific character to indicate the end of the response, there are infinite ways.

A correct implementation would loop through several receives() until the data was fully received (or a timeout expires).

In other words, the device seems to be sending out data much slower than you imagine and a straight run (no debugging stops) will just catch a partial response.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I had to add Thread.sleep(300) after sending and receiving to make it work!